# Adding gpg-exported ssh key to ssh-agent

Tags: linux, ssh, git, gnupg

I exported one authentication key from gpg to a public ssh key (with the `--export-ssh-key`), now I'd like to add its privat key with `ssh-add` to be able to clone a repository on github through the ssh link, but I'm clueless *where* the privat key is which I can simply add as an argument to `ssh-add`.

Can anyone explain me please, where the "ssh-privat"-key is which I should add with `ssh-agent`?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it thanks to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#SSH_agent).

I just needed to add this variable:

```bash
SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
```